# BSD Software license usage

Tags: licensing, bsd-license

We are a company and we want to use 30% of the BSD opensource software to plug and play it with our source code, can we do that. Further this program will not be distributed and only will be accessed by our clients using our own software. Is it possible for us to do the above without any restrictions.

Kindly give me feedback on the above soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The usual IANAL applies; if you need legal advice, consult a lawyer.

That said, the spirit of the BSD license is that you can do pretty much anything you like, except claim you wrote code that you did not write.

There are different flavors of the BSD license; some include an attribution clause (if you redistribute, you must attribute code you derived from to the original authors) and / or a non-endorsement clause (you cannot use the original product name, nor the names of the original authors, to endorse your derived product). But other than that, you are free to derive and reuse as you see fit.

For some perspective: even Windows includes a few pieces of BSD-licensed code.

Answer (score 1):

BSD means you can pretty much do what you want with it except claim it was our own invention - read the licence